# Where to store public key of an asymmetric cryptosystem?

Tags: public-key, ecies

I am developing an application that uses ECIES encryption and I am currently storing private keys in secure place on each peer and storing public keys in a shared database (accessible by all peers). Is this a problem?

Logically knowing a public key of some peer allows me to send him a message, and no risk because the private key is unknown. Can someone explain to me whether this approach is secure?

Comment: The more interesting problem is probably who can modify the public data base and how are (changed) public keys verified?

Comment: Peers are not allowed to change the stored public data, they can only add new public keys

Comment: The database would need to include not only the public key, but also the identity of the owner of the public key.  What if the attacker added a new public key, associated with the identity of someone else?  Also, how does someone update their public key?  Could someone else do that same procedure?